# ASP.NET MVC - Help needed to Improve the code for Drop-Down Box?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created the below drop-down to populate a list of cities.

All works fine, but I would like to know the better ways of doing this please. Also, please let me know if it is possible to create the same drop down using < Select > instead of HTML helpers.

Below are my DTO classes. Please advise if I can make improvements in the controller and the view as well.

```
//ViewModel

public class LocationDTO
{
    public IEnumerable<CityDTO> Cities { get; set; }
    public LocationDTO()
    {
        this.Cities = new CityDTO[] { };
    }
}

public class CityDTO
{
    public string CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my Controller, and I've used entity framework database first approach to get the data back from database. Could you please address the improvements that needs to be done on my controller ?

```
//Controller

Models.LocationDTO Loc = new Models.LocationDTO();
EF.LocationEntities locCtx = new EF.LocationEntities();

public Action Result Index() {
    using(locCtx) { 
        var locResults    = (from q in locCtx.usp_GetAllCities()
                       Select new Models.CityDTO {
                       CityId = q.Id, 
                       CityName = q.Name  }); 
        loc.Cities = locResults.ToList();
    }

    List<Models.CityDTO> citiesList = new List<Models.CityDTO>();
    Models.CityDTO city = new Models.CityDTO() { CityId = "-1", CityName = "Select City" };
    citiesList.Add(city);
    citiesList.AddRange(Loc.Cities.ToList());

    ViewBag.CitiesDropDown = citiesList;
    return view(loc);
}
```

Below is my View. I'd also like to know how the Lamdba expression works in this scenario please.

```
//View

@{
    List<TestApp.Models.CityDTO> citiesList = ViewBag.CitiesDropDown;
    var cityItems = new SelectList(citiesList, "CityId", "CityName");
}
<div>
    Cities: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Cities.SingleOrDefault().CityID, @cityItems)
</div>
```

Comment: This question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since you only want a review of your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of improvements that could be done on your controller.

Let's start by abstracting the data access:

```
public interface ICitiesRepository
{
    IEnumerable<City> GetAll();
}
```

and then have an implementation:

```
public class CitiesRepositoryEF: ICitiesRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<City> GetAll()
    {
        using (var ctx = new LocationEntities())
        {
            return ctx.usp_GetAllCities().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Alright, now let's define a view model for our view:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedCityId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Next comes the controller:

```
public class CitiesController: Controller
{
    private readonly ICitiesRepository repository;
    public CitiesController(ICitiesRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        model.Cities = this
            .repository
            .GetAll()
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name
            });
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("Thanks for selecting city: " + model.SelectedCityId);
    }
}
```

and finally you will have a corresponding view which will of course be strongly typed to the view model:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCityId, Model.Cities, "Select City")
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Now all that's left is to configure your favorite dependency injection framework to inject the `CitiesRepositoryEF` concrete instance into controllers.

Comment: Wow..This is awesome..!!.Thanks a lot.!!.Bit too advanced for me as i'm still going through a learning curve, but will definitely give it a shot...So to finish things off, I make use of a dependency injection framework like Ninject and register the repository in Global.asax ? -Thanks

Comment: Exactly. You could install the `Ninject.MVC3` NuGet package which will create an `~/App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs` where you could configure the dependency inside the `RegisterServices` method: `kernel.Bind<ICitiesRepository>().To<CitiesRepositoryEF>();`.